# Validate field/attribute in CRM Dynamics forms using js

Tags: javascript, validation, crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I have a problem in validating attribute on a form in CRM dynamics.
I added a JavaScript code that validate the attribute value based on my business rules.
and added to 2 events, form on save and field on change,

the question is:

1- Is this the best way to validate on attribute?

2- In case of using this way, how can i stop saving the form or passing it as valid ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that's a good way to validate input. In case you want to stop save in case one of validations fails do following:

1. Check "Pass execution context" during registration of save event handler.
2. Add parameter to function that's called during save procedure.
3. In case your validation fails call following code:

   execObj.getEventArgs().preventDefault()

You can find more details here -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509060.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this information, but the problem in this solution that it redirect to the cases page with simple error message ,
is there another way to control this message

Comment: What Andrii has mentioned should work for your requirement. Can you please elaborate on what exactly is required?

Comment: What exactly required is to make this validation looks like the OOB validations that makes red 'X' beside the field and so on.

Comment: You can add notification to a field  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setnotification and put focus on it.